# How to Flutter download path change

Tags: flutter, file, directory, download

I am using background_downloader package for download file in flutter.

Here a function, I made

```
 Future<void> startDownload(
    BuildContext context,
    String? fileUrl,
    String? fileName,
  ) async {
    final status = await Permission.storage.request();
    String savedDir = "";
    if (status.isGranted) {
      // await getExternalStorageDirectory()
      //     .then((value) => savedDir = value!.path);
      // print(savedDir);

      /// define the download task (subset of parameters shown)
      final task = DownloadTask(
          url: fileUrl!,
          urlQueryParameters: {'q': 'pizza'},
          filename: fileName,
          headers: {'myHeader': 'value'},
          baseDirectory: BaseDirectory.applicationSupport,
          directory: "/Downloads",
          updates:
              Updates.statusAndProgress, // request status and progress updates
          requiresWiFi: false,
          retries: 5,
          allowPause: true,
          metaData: 'data for me');

      // Start download, and wait for result. Show progress and status changes
// while downloading
      final TaskStatusUpdate result = await FileDownloader().download(task,
          onProgress: (progress) => print('Progress: ${progress * 100}%'),
          onStatus: (status) async {
            await FileDownloader().openFile(task: task);
          });

// Act on the result

      // switch (result) {
      //   case TaskStatus.complete:
      //     print('Success!');
      //     break;

      //   case TaskStatus.canceled:
      //     print('Download was canceled');
      //     break;

      //   case TaskStatus.paused:
      //     print('Download was paused');
      //     break;

      //   default:
      //     print('Download not successful');
      //     break;
      // }
    } else {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Permission Required'),
          content: Text('Storage permission is required to download files.'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

But I can't change the base directory. I want to download file in main download folder. How can I ?